# Translation of this Python Line

Tags: python, dictionary

I am relatively new to Python and having problem translating the following one line:

```
diffList = [key for key in set(dict1n.keys() + dict2.keys()) if dict1.get(key) != dict2t.get(key)]
```

Can someone please rewrite it for me - break it down into multiple lines in a "normal" nice format?

I think - and I am not sure - what the line is trying to do is to compare two dictionaries and output the differences to a list.

Thanks.

UPDATE: I had typos in the line - there should only be dict1 and dict2:

```
diffList = [key for key in set(dict1.keys() + dict2.keys()) if dict1.get(key) != dict2.get(key
```

Answer (score 3):

That translates to:

```
diffList = []
for key in set(dict1.keys() + dict2.keys()):
    if dict1.get(key) != dict2.get(key):
        diffList.append(key)
```

What this basically does is it generates a new list, with the unique values from both dicts. Not that those values are unique per key, and not necessarily unique global.

A set is a datastructure where there can be only one entry for each unique value. So it will make sure that it only has unique items. This will make sure that you only check each key once.

*Update*: Changed some things according to the updates to the question.

Comment: Oops, sorry I had a typo - there should only be dict1 and dict2 i.e. 2 dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted is a ["List Comprehension"](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

It translates to:

```
diffList = []
for key in  set(dict1n.keys() + dict2.keys()):
  if dict1.get(key) != dict2t.get(key):
    diffList.append(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

In English it is:

List those keys that:

- are present in at least one of the dictionaries
- but do not have the same values in both dictionaries

  - treating the cases: `dictX[key] is None` and: `key not in dictY` as having the same value (that's how `dict.get()`works.)

Answer (score 1):

In English:

1. Get all keys and store them into a `set` -> `set(dict1n.keys() + dict2.keys())`
2. Iterate through them -> `key for key in set(...)`
3. Get these keys, that have different values in the different maps: `if dict1.get(key) != dict2t.get(key)`
   (only the keys, that are in both sets : because `dictX.get(key)` will return `None`, if the key is not in `dictX`, but the same key *will be* in the other set then )
4. These keys are stored into a list: `diffList = [ key ... ]`

Comment: Is it too much to ask to **update** the answer to use real words?

Comment: Real words matter to people who need to see real words.  Not every can read English slang.